# filesend using webview which one should I set for the value section

Tags: android, html

I should have html with File Attribute

```
 <input type="file" value="">
```

I accessed to the gallery and select image file and following is onActivity result

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != intent){
               Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setFileUri('" + selectedImage.toString() + "')");
               String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setFilePath('" + path + "')");


               BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
               options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);


               ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
               byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
               String imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
               String image = "data:image/png;base64," + imageBase64;
               String temp = "./img/logo.png";
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setImage('"+ image  +"')");
               //Iview01.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               //saveBitmaptoJpeg(bitmap,"img","temp",web,path);


           }
        }
    }
```

gallery returned Bitmap format for image file. 
 
My question is when you send file to the server or DB. 
How should I set value="" ??
what should I put into the value section?

```
   <input type="file" value="">
```

when I load picture file from android gallery. 
which one should I put for the value section to send the file to the database or server?

Answer (score 0):

i don't see *name* attribute there !

You must put it in order to be able to get the file to the server side

```
<input type="file" name="inputname" >
```

don't need **value** here.

Comment: that is not my question.  I just put temporary <input type>